# How to the values of an array to populate the keys of another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of field names. I would like to use those to populate the keys of another array, which will have empty values as default. Is there a single command I can do this with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of PHP 5.2.0 you can also use [`array_fill_keys`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php)

```
array_fill_keys( array('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), NULL);
```

which will give

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 
    [bar] => 
    [baz] => 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) and [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill) functions:

```
array_combine($arrayOfKeys, array_fill(0, count($arrayOfKeys), null))
```

Or, as `array_fill` is only available since PHP 4.2, try [`array_pad`](http://php.net/array_pad) instead:

```
array_combine($arrayOfKeys, array_pad(array(), count($arrayOfKeys), null))
```

Comment: *only available since PHP 4.2* - Released: 22 April 2002 http://de3.php.net/releases/ ;)

Comment: @Gordon: It’s sad, but there are servers out there that still have a lower PHP version running.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you need [`array_combine()`](http://it.php.net/array_combine)